# How to send and receive a reply to the bot

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have tried to understand the Microsoft SDK reference in how to communicate with the bot but there is simply no clear way shown of interacting with it.. From the documentation this is what I could put down so far:

```html
const { BotFrameworkAdapter } = require('botbuilder');

const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: '123',
    appPassword: '123'
});

// Start a new conversation with the user
adapter.createConversation()
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Where is other part of code that listens to messages? for example `/api/messages`
is the API that listens to messages

Comment: I dont want to use any local server api. If you look at other bots like amazon lex, the sdk jsut provides the methods to communicate and that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft Bot Framework makes use of the restify server to create an API endpoint for the bot. A bot is simply a web service that will send and receive messages to and from the Bot Connector. You will have to use the following steps to communicate with the bot:

- Install Restify

```
  npm install --save restify
```

- Include the restify module

```
  const restify = require('restify');
```

- Set up the restify server

```
    const server = restify.createServer();
    server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978,
        function () {
            console.log(`\n${ server.name } listening to ${ server.url }`);
        }
    );
```

- Create the main dialog (here the example uses Echo Bot)

```
const bot = new EchoBot();
```

- Create a POST endpoint for your server and hook up the adapter to listen for incoming requests

```
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
        // route to main dialog.
        await bot.run(context);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.